# java chat server multiple serversockets for handling different featues

Tags: java, sockets, chat, server

I'm studying java and have a little question. I'm currently making a multi-threaded chat server which works fine. It looks a little lite MSN messenger, when you connect you se an onlinelist, and theh you double click on name to open a chatwindow.

The server has 2 serverSockets for each client.

The first one is handling the onlinelist and updates and removes users.
The second one is handling the messages. (I made two seperate because I didn't want the userlist's names to collide with the messages).

My question is if I want to add a feature so the clients can send files to eachother, should I make a third ServerSocket for that one?

Or have i build the program completly wrong?

Comment: Well, if it works it is not wrong. Personally, I' d use some protocol over one connection. But sending files can be time consuming. So handling those on a different line seems to be a good idea.

Comment: Ok thanks for answer! Do you know where i could find some tutorials on protocols that you mentioned? I have only studied Java for 2 months so we haven't started with that yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are building the application incorrectly. You want a single socket server which pulls messages then dispatches them to a set of workers. You can have one worker per message type if you wish. The workers should not know anything about network layers. They should take a command and return a value. The network class which gave them the command should handle writing the result back to the client. This way all the network and security logic can be in the server class, and each worker can focus on its specialist tasks without knowing about the network. You should then write junit tests which test each worker in isolation without needing the network class. Then your main program simply has to create and configure your (junit tested!) workers, instantiate the server class, and give it your workers, the call the start methods to bring up your server. Welcome to software engineering the first step to wisdom is to seek learning by asking such questions.

**Edit** I forgot to answer the file handling question :-) A real chat service may have low bandwidth to the client (eg phone). Throwing large files over another socket may saturate the available client bandwidth making chatting a poor experience whilst many files try to upload over one or many sockets. A good approach is to pull small chunks of the file and add to a bounded queue (LinkedBlockingQueue). Then peek the next file chunk on the queue to send alternated with user chat commands. On the server the network class reads the next message which may be a chunk or chat command and dispatches to the appropriate worker.

There could be a "start file upload command" which has the network server class create a new FileUploadWorker per file to allow concurrency uploads. Then on the client there could be, say three, files being chunked into the single queue, and three workers on the server, one per file, whilst the user is chatting with their chat commands always going to the server first ahead of queued file chunks which are lower priority than actual chat.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer!! Do you know any tutorials I could take a look at or what I should search for?

Comment: Folks use frameworks rather than write from scratch. Experimenting with doing it from scratch is educational so good to try; yet using a mature framework which lets you plugin your business logic is more cost effective than writing framework code yourself; security, authentication, encryption, error handling, thread model, session handling, all take effort and many generations of teams, opensourced, documented, tested, so good to reuse. Now you see the basics experiment with Netty http://netty.io/ as its low level yet rich; raw sockets yes but also websockets, encryption, high concurrency, etc

Comment: with regards to my last comment about frameworks you should definitely finish your little chat app first as you will learn a lot from making the app.